# How to set no spacing in UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I'm trying to do a UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout with 3 items to a row at a third of the screen width. For some reason it's adding spacing and not conforming to the square layout.

Here are the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout functions.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     let yourWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width/3.0) - 2

     let yourHeight = yourWidth



        return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        //return UIEdgeInsets.zero
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0);
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }
```

Please do not suggest adding a layout to a collection view in the viewDidLoad method. I tried that and it didn't work because it deletes my header.

Comment: (collectionView.bounds.width - 2) / 3.0 I think this is the formula to calculate 1/3 width with only 1 pixel spacing between cells

Comment: can you tell me your xcode version?

Answer (score 0):

```
class VC : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
 let yourWidth = (collectionView.frame.width - 4)/3
      // your minimumInteritemSpacing is 1, hence 4

 let yourHeight = yourWidth

    return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
}



}
```

You can also try:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout?.estimatedItemSize = .init()
    layout?.headerReferenceSize = .init()

 }
```

Comment: the first doesn't work. is there more code to the second one? also if I use the second one that seems to delete my header. how can I keep the header while using the second one?

Comment: How did you set the header size ? I edited my answer , you can add : layout?.headerReferenceSize = .init()

Comment: I set the header size in storyboard. this still does not work after the edits. it just appears as the same size but at the top of the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     let marginsAndInsets = inset * 2 + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.left + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.right + minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(cellsPerRow - 1)

        //set inset, minimumInteritemSpacing and cellsPerRow globally

        let itemSize = ((collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)).rounded(.down)

        return CGSize(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        //return UIEdgeInsets.zero
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0);
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }
```